# How to deal with networking loops that are too fast?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, network-programming, sleep

I have a program with a connections processing thread that has a loop. The problem is that the loop runs too fast and consumes 100% CPU core.

I tried putting a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));`(or similar) at the end if there are no clients(obviously the problem still exists when there are clients), it does solve the CPU hogging, but it also introduces delay to responding to new connections. The sleep is unreliable and can't be too small usually results in > 1ms. And if the sleep is small it doesn't really result in efficient sleeping anyway (1-3% CPU core consumption).

What is a good way to deal with it?

Comment: If I'm right, you're effectively asking how to avoid being DDoSed by clients connecting to your service/application over a network?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I'm just crap at asking, and the fact that I am new to the concepts mentioned makes it even more difficult. On a side note, I doubt you can avoid being DDoSed since you don't know who's a valid client, even if you verify somehow, each verification would probably result in the same effect.

Comment: Well, exactly! :) If your problem is not that network activity is constant, just that you're not _blocking_ waiting on I/O activity (or polling for it as shown in answers below) then you're okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active waiting is rarely a good idea. it is typically a better approach to delegate the wait to the system and be awaken whenever an event occurs.

On Linux systems, [`poll()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) does exactly this:

```
#include <poll.h>
// ...
::poll(&fds, nfds, timeout);
```

Waits (block) `timeout` milliseconds for an event to occur on any file descriptor of `fds`.

---

As an alternative for not-related-to-file-descriptor cases, I'd use `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()`. Those work with a mutex and a condition:

- `pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex)` unlocks `mutex`and immediately put the thread to sleep until `cond` is met (signaled), but then it reacquires the mutex.
- `pthread_cond_signal(&cond)` signals all threads waiting on `cond` that a condition might have changed.

A typical usage would be:

```
worker thread:
    ::pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (condition == false) {
        ::pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); // passive wait
    }
    // this part is only invoked when:
    // - condition is true
    // - mutex has been acquired
    ::pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

thread handling connection/deconnection:
    ::pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // add/remove clients
    ::pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    ::pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

See:

- [pthread_cond_wait()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait)
- [pthread_cond_signal()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)
- [pthread_cond_init()/pthread_cond_destroy()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init)

Comment: It is similar to `select(...)`. But what about the case where you don't have sockets or don't want the thread to even know about them? I know you are just answering the question since I mentioned networking(it's likely I asked a bad question), but I was hoping there is a more general case?

Comment: @JustinBieber General case is OS specific and is to use things like blocking reads, semaphores, etc.  Operations that cause your program to be blocked waiting for a kernel event.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm really trying to avoid directly operating on socket descriptors since overall design is abstracted code. How would you do something like that using semaphores? I imagine you could have another thread doing checks and unlocking/locking the mutex, but then you'd have the same problem of checking thread being too fast.

Comment: There is no general solution: file descriptors on linux => `poll()`, shared resource amongst threads => mutex, ... If you need a special solution, ask a precise question.

Comment: @YSC How would you use a mutex in this case(or any case with a custom end-result boolean condition)?

Comment: @YSC it seems I'm new to conditional variables as a concept to synchronize thread activity. Although my problem is left due to my own ignorance, you have answered the question that was given(albeit not precisely the one I needed to ask) and rightfully introduced me to this concept. I'll accept the answer and ask a new question if I'm stuck on the design or concept. Thank you. The only note I could make from thinking on your is that C++11 has these conditional things, I think the standard solution would always be better than linux-specific.

Comment: @JustinBieber Yes it does, and yes C++ `std::thread` and alike are a prefered solution to linux-specific.